# How to apply a function can test whether an element in a list in data frame with python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

For a data frame `df`, it has a column `col` contains `list` value:

```
 id    col
 1     [1, 10, 23]
 2     [2, 11, 19, 29]
 ..
```

I tried:

```
df[1 in df.col]
```

But got an error:

```
KeyError: True
```

Do you know how can I implement it appropriately? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Psidom Sorry I have edited it already. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option using `apply`
`df.col.apply(lambda x: 1 in x)`

***demo***
`df[df.col.apply(lambda x: 1 in x)]`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try read the "apply" function in pandas [document](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
df['has_element'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: element in x)
```